# machine learning preventing overfitting is this cheating?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

When evaluating train/test results during training say these values come:

```
Train: 50.5% - Test: 50.2%
Train: 55.5% - Test: 53.2%
Train: 62.5% - Test: 58.2%
Train: 69.5% - Test: 62.2%
Train: 75.5% - Test: 59.2% <--- stop training, overfitting seems to be happening.
```

Can you stop a model from training when this occurs, or is it cheating? I.e stopping the model from training when the test accuracy decreases. I know that you are supposed to only evaluate the training set during training so that is why I am wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is cheating. Model trained in such a way does not have any reasonable guarantees about how it will perform "in real life"

What you are supposed to do is to have a separate mechanism of detecting when learning is finished (it seems that your training is iterative), which might either analyze the model itself, or use some separate (often called Validation) hold-out part of the dataset.

In short: you cannot use test data to **anything** besides reporting final value, you cannot base **any decisions on it**.

Comment: Same comment that I gave to axiom. What happens when test data results are not up to par? Can you start over or is that cheating also?

Comment: it is also cheating. Obviously hard to avoid when developing new method, but this is a known phenomenon. This is why for perfect evaluation, dealing with this psyhological problem - it is better to not have access to test data at all, and ask someone else to do final evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you are doing.

If you are using the test accuracy to fit hyper-parameters, then yes, you are cheating. The test data is "leaking" into your training data indirectly and you are overfitting.

Thus, it is advisable to have 3 datasets: Train, Test and *Validation* data.

**Lock the Test data away, do not touch it till you take hands off tweaking your model (training).**

Use the validation data as much as you like to find the best hyperparameters etc.

When you are done, unlock the Test data to report the accuracy of your model (and just to emphasize, *do not use this feedback to tweak your model*).

If you are not happy with the accuracy you get on the test data, consider rethinking your model. If you are not happy with the test data results, you won't be happy once the model is in production.

If you don't have enough data to create three partitions, consider doing [k-fold cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what happens when test data results are not as good as you want them to be after tweaking the validation data set. Can you start over or is that cheating?

Comment: @shell Then you need to do something about your model, because it will anyways not perform well in production.

Comment: I see thanks. Hard to decide who to upvote both answers are good and answer what I need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do that (assuming you have yet a third set of data, sometimes called the "validation" set). It is called early stopping. I don't think there's anything to gain by doing that; whether or not you stop early depends the relative positions of the optimal parameters for the training and validation sets. If I remember correctly, about half the time you will stop early, and half the time you won't.